# ExtJS 5 What is wrong with Form?

Tags: forms, extjs, field

I am trying my hands on ExtJS 5. when I use this code -

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/anchoring.html

What I get is -

[image]

Can you please guide me what is going wrong for me? Why am I not getting the form with fields well stretched as shown in the link?

[EDIT]
I don't know what was the reason, when I restarted my machine it started working fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have tried the link and got expected result. Post your code here for solution.

Comment: thanks Igor Semin and Anand for the helping hand. It looks like when I do build build using sencha command it starts working for me fine as shown in the example. Semin, I am using the code in the link. No changes.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention Ext JS 5 then point us to some code that references Ext JS 4?

Comment: Hi Colin. I am sorry if this post is causing trouble. I am using extjs 5 and I assumed that a simple code shown in the link will work even if it from extjs 4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code. Something is up with the way I am using extjs 5. When I do a srncha build then this code works fine for me even on non sencha build(bootstrap.js). No clue why but I am able to proceed with development. Thanks all for your efforts and time :)